# How to process a list of files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, directory

in MATLAB, my function is like this:

```
 names = {'d:\C001\C001_Deo.csv','d:\C001\C001_Oxy.csv','d:\C001\C001_Tal.csv'}
 data_conversion(names)         %this function creat a folder in C001 to save results
```

I have 100 folders named as `C001`, `C002`, `...`, `C100`. Each folder has three `.csv` files, named like this: `C001_Deo.csv`, `C001_Oxy.csv`, `C001_Tal.csv`,  `C002_Deo.csv`, `C002_Oxy.csv`, `C002_Tal.csv`, ...

Does anyone can help me to write a loop so I can run `data_conversion(names)` at a time to get all the results. Then I don't need to run it 100 times. 
I tried many times but failed. Thanks!

Comment: Show your failed attempts. See [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
baseFolder = 'd:\';

for i=1:100
    % get a string for  001 -> 100
    strtmp = num2str(i);
    str = cat(2,repmat('0',1,3-length(strtmp)),strtmp);

    % reconstitute folder path
    folderString = [baseFolder 'C' str filesep];

    % and the 3 file paths
    f1 = [folderString 'C' str '_Deo.csv'];
    f2 = [folderString 'C' str '_Oxy.csv'];
    f3 = [folderString 'C' str '_Tal.csv'];

    % run your data_conversion function
    data_conversion({f1 f2 f3}) 


end
```

Comment: this is what i need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your filenames are stored in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html). `names(1)` returns the first cell of `names`. `names{1}` returns the content of the first cell, so your loop will look like this

```
names = {'d:\C001\C001_Deo.csv','d:\C001\C001_Oxy.csv','d:\C001\C001_Tal.csv'}

for loopi = 1:length(names)
     data_conversion(names{loopi})
end
```

I assume all your files are in a single location, so you might want to get the list of files automatically:

```
folders = dir('d:\C*');

for loopi = 1:length(folders)
  % if order matters
  folder = strcat(folders(loopi).folder,'\',folders(loopi).name);
  f1 = dir([folder,'\*_Deo.csv']);
  f2 = dir([folder,'\*_Oxy.csv']);
  f3 = dir([folder,'\*_Tal.csv']);
  data_conversion({f1(1).name, f2(1).name, f3(1).name});
end
```

`dir` returns a [struct array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), which is indexed with parenthesis instead of brackets.

Comment: when I run     folders(loop).folder , I got an error: "Reference to non-existent field 'folder'."  But anyway, I got my problem solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If your function needs the entire cell array at once, then here's an option:

```
Cnum     = strsplit(strtrim(sprintf('C%03d ', 1:100)))';
basepath = 'D:';    
complete = @(str) fullfile(basepath, Cnum, strcat(Cnum, '_', str, '.csv'));
pths     = [complete('Deo') complete('Oxy') complete('Tal')];
```

Otherwise, go with Laure's solution.

Comment: it helps me. Thank you very much!